# How to check Hadith reference

Tags: hadith, dua, reference-request, sahih-bukhari

have downloaded this app Hinsul Muslim it contains all the duas . So tell mehow to check reference of Hadith the reference the app gives is like Bukhari 7/158 how to convert that fraction in Hadith no please tell me someone[image: this image is the ss of Hinsul app it has given the reference from which the dua is but how to search the reference of Bukhari what does the number in fractions mean]

Comment: [This](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/66) is the hadith.

Comment: Okay thanks for providing me the haidth but how the reference of Hinsul Muslim gets connected to the refermece of Hadith of Sunnah.com

Comment: Read the answer in the second comment. There is no universal numbering system for ahadith. The app is referencing some volume\page number from some specific publisher.